# android Wear 5.0 can't resolve host (Http , AsyncClient ETC. )

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, androidhttpclient, android-async-http

I ve developed Android Wear App also SDK is 4.4AW. After finished that applitacion  I tested on new android wear SDK that is 5.0.1 Emulator AND motorola360(with 5.0.1) then I recived this errror (Show in the below)

Message Sum:

> can't resolve host

Detailed Message:

> Unable to resolve host "URL": No address associated with hostname

The App works perfect on 4.4 android wear but failed on 5.0.1 (I used Android studio and there is no Error before execution , Successful Build, Crash on Emulator.)

Im certainly sure that I used internet permision as u can see :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

Glade Detail :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.hakyazilim.onlywear"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.87'
    compile files ('lib/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
}
```

I used "android-async-http-1.4.3.jar" Lib. Following this Code :

```
String requestURL = "My ASPX page (includes XML)";

    asyncHttpClient.get(requestURL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            try {
                mTextView.setText(response.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(">>>>", "Part 1 Load Fail !");
            }
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
 //"EROR = can't resolve host"
        }
    });

Best regards
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct internet connection on Android Wear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627174/direct-internet-connection-on-android-wear)

Comment: As explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627174/direct-internet-connection-on-android-wear the Android Wear devices don't have access to a direct Internet connection. The calls should be done by the handheld device and synchronized with the data layer api.

Comment: But I could connect internet on wear (4.4W2) directly. I think this rules belongs 5.0 :(

Answer (score 1):

Even if Android 5.1.1 support Wi-Fi Feature.

It impossible to directly access the Internet in Android Wear.

You should stick to the Data Layer API , you cannot send http request directly from watch. Fetch internet data from the phone, then transfer it to watch with Data Layer API.﻿

You can see this [Does Android Wear support directly access the Internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259692/does-android-wear-support-directly-access-the-internet)

And this document [Always-on and Wi-Fi with the latest Android Wear update](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2015/05/always-on-and-wi-fi-with-latest-android.html)