# Is there any way to call webservice from android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

i'm trying to call a webservice from android wear and it's working fine in the emulator, but don't receive any thing in the real device (moto 360).
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android Wear 5.0 can't resolve host (Http , AsyncClient ETC. )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712834/android-wear-5-0-cant-resolve-host-http-asyncclient-etc)

Answer (score 0):

First, note that not all wear devices have wifi radios. Secondly, for those devices that do have wifi radio, wifi connectivity is only available when the wear device is not directly connected to its paired phone (via BT). So if your wear device has wifi radio and is not connected, then you can make calls over network from your wear device but if you solely rely on that, it is not going to be very reliable since most of the times your wear device is connected to the paired phone. You can check out [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary) which takes this into account and makes http calls possible either directly or via the paired phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing experience.