# Enable internet connection - Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wifi, android-internet

I'm developing my first `android wear` application and I'm doing a request to an `api`, the problem is that I don't have internet connection. How can I enable the internet connection or something like that?

so far what I have tried is enable the bluetooth connection but every time I click there I get the following error Unfortunately, settings has stopped.

[image]

any idea how to fix it?

Note: below is my virtual machine details:

[image]
[image]

**EDITED**
Also to make sure the internet connection is not working I have tried the code below:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
```

Comment: did you add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE to the permissions ?

Comment: Yep.. I have tried the app in the phone and is working. Any idea? @keatsPeeks

Comment: Oh, I thought your were talking about the app. Android Wear Devices have no direct access to the internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627174/direct-internet-connection-on-android-wear

Comment: So how can I add access to it? Because the Bluetooth doesn't work..

Comment: By communicating with the app via the data layer API : http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

Comment: Have you apllied
 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/> in manifest ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes as it is documented that a wear does not have the direct access to internet so you cant call the API directlly from android wear.

There is a work around which i have used in one app i recently developed in wear.

You have to user the Message API for the android device and wear. Using this you can communicate with device and wear.

You can pass the action in Message API from device to wear.
So what you can do is based on a specific action you can pass control to device call the API got the data and pass the required data to wear and do the operation you need.

And yes it is important that Google Play service is same or updated on both android device and wear (Device or Emulator) otherwise it will throw exception.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**
The new Android Wear 2.0 allows the direct internet connection

Comment: Right, it's supposed to, but the emulator still isn't _doing it_

Answer (score 0):

Running it from the terminal and manually setting a dns-server did the trick for me:

```
emulator -list-avds
emulator -avd Wear_OS_Small_Round_API_30 -netdelay none -netspeed full -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

In this command snippet, I used the **first command** to **see** the **name** **of** the Wear OS **emulator**, and the **second** **command** to **run** the **emulator** with full speed internet using Google's DNS server.

As a sidenote, here's my .zshrc variables to run these commands:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/${USER}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/emulator
```

Comment: so far this has been working fine for me, but sometimes i'd need to turn on the airplane mode and turn it back off